# Running .Net Core Application with docker container but i have an issue like this `0.0.0.0:7001->7001/tcp`

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, ip, port

I try to containerize my `.net core` application but i have an issue on app container ports. It seems as `0.0.0.0:7001->7001/tcp`. I think problem exists because of this. Is there any other problems on there?

My dockerfile and docker-compose file like below

Dockerfile

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1-nanoserver-1903 AS base
    WORKDIR /app

    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1-nanoserver-1903 AS build
    WORKDIR /src
    COPY ["Blog.Web/Blog.Web.csproj", "Blog.Web/"]
    COPY ["Blog.BLL/Blog.BLL.csproj", "Blog.BLL/"]
    COPY ["Blog.DAL/Blog.DAL.csproj", "Blog.DAL/"]
    COPY ["Blog.Models/Blog.Models.csproj", "Blog.Models/"]
    RUN dotnet restore "Blog.Web/Blog.Web.csproj"
    COPY . .
    WORKDIR "/src/Blog.Web"
    RUN dotnet build "Blog.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app

    FROM build AS publish
    RUN dotnet publish "Blog.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app

    FROM base AS final
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=publish /app .
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Blog.Web.dll"]
```

Docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  client:
    build:
      dockerfile: Blog.Web\Dockerfile
      context: .
    ports:
      - "7001:7001"
```

Bash Display

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                 CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
b5e3edcbc969        blogwebapplication_client   "dotnet Blog.Web.dll"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:7001->7001/tcp   blogwebapplication_client_1
```

When I try to access my app on localhost:7001 I get an error:

> "This site cant be reach".

Comment: You exposed the port 7001 to your real machine's network. Is it a problem? What is your expectation?

Comment: I try to access my app on http://localhost:7001 address but i see error on browser that is "This site cant be reach".

Comment: Please use `docker run -it` to view the outputs of the container and check if the ASP.NET Core process started and listening to the port.

Comment: Than you for concerning. I think problem was solved for just now but still I have to connect sql server to my project.